# How to list Docker containers of a Mesos Marathon Application?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I understand the basic concepts of running a Docker container on Mesos with [this](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/) and [this](https://open.mesosphere.com/advanced-course/deploying-a-web-app-using-docker/) as an Marathon application. I have two questions:

1. Does Mesos/Marathon has a REST API to list Docker containers started by a Marathon application? I went through [REST API reference](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/rest-api.html) but could not find a way to do this. What I'm looking for is the IP addresses of the Docker containers within the Mesos cluster/network.
2. Does Mesos provide a [Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel) like SDN for Docker or is it just local IP addresses containers would get for each Mesos slave? I checked [this](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html) but could not figure this out.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/generated/api.html#v2_tasks_get

There you can see that the task objects contain `host` and `ports` properties.